# CodeIgniter, short UL not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I can access to http://myip/test/codeigniter/ intead of http://myip/test/codeigniter/index.php/. A good point

But I can not access to the following URL:

http://myip/test/codeigniter/welcome

http://myip/test/codeigniter/welcome/index

http://myip/test/codeigniter/index.php/welcome

http://myip/test/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/index

In application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

The .htaccess on the root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

Apache has well loaded the `rewrite_module`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Add `http://myip/test/codeigniter/` to `$config['base_url']` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

To this (notice the `?`):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```